# How to increment time by 1 hour

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have two time values. one for the previous login time and one for the current login time. 
I have to increase previous time login by one hour. I have used the date format hh:mm:ss.
This is my code snippet.

```
Date previous_time, current_time;

  if(previous_time.before(current_time)){
  Log.i("Time Comparision"," true");
 }
```

so instead of the above mentioned if condition, I have to add one hour to the previous_time and do the if condition. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.setTime(previous_time);
   calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
   previous_time = calendar.getTime();
   // do your comparison
```

Comment: Sorry to say my friend. This code updates the hour, but it totally changes my date format. I want only time in the format "hh:mm:ss".

Comment: @Andro_Selva - Formatting and the actual manipulation of the date are two independent tasks. Look at [DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) and/or [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Then you can use SimpleDateFormat to get your wanted format. In your case "new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(previous_time)", after the last line of planetjones.

Comment: Yep agree with @Rob Hruska (+1) - as the JavaDoc states "The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision" - formatting it is different to performing operations such as comparisons on it.

Comment: @Andro_Selva, do you want to post some more code or explain your problem exactly - I can't infer what your issue is when you say "it didnt bring any difference"

Answer (score 5):

```
previous_time.setTime(previous_time.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

or

```
Date session_expiry = new Date(previous_time.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    Date date = Utils.getBookingDate(mBooking.ToTime);
    Calendar calendarAdd = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarAdd.setTime(date);
    calendarAdd.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    toTime = sdf.format(calendarAdd.getTime());
    tv_Totime.setText(toTime);
```

when current time string formate within add 1 hours