# How to add an hour to my time

Tags: java, datetime

I have my time in the below format, and I use this value to set the text of my button.

```
String strDateFormat = "HH:mm: a";
SimpleDateFormat sdf ;
 sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
startTime_time_button.setText(sdf.format(date));
```

Now my question is, 
is it possible to add one hour to this time format?

Comment: Hm, maybe like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950417/how-to-increment-time-by-1-hour

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005523/how-to-add-one-day-to-a-date

Comment: You have already posted nearly the same question (the one linked by joe776).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best and easiest way is using Apache Commons Lang:

```
Date incrementedDate = DateUtils.addHour(startDate, 1);
```

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html

Answer (score 11):

You have to use `Calendar`:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
date = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: `HOUR_OF_YEAR` probably `DAY` :)

Comment: No, you don't ***have*** to :) And the problem is, sometimes you can't (Android, GAE).

Answer (score 5):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(setYourTimeHereInDateObj);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
Date timeAfterAnHour = cal.getTime();
//now format this time
```

**See**

- [Calendar API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: Could I use GregorianCalendar in Android? Like so: Calendar mcalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
mcalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use Jabal's suggestion (i.e. you are not allowed to use non-JDK libraries), you can use this:

```
long hour = 3600 * 1000; // 3600 seconds times 1000 milliseconds
Date anotherDate = new Date(date.getTime() + hour);
```

If by a chance you are looking for time zone conversion, you can simply assign one to your formatter, it would work faster:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"); // put your time zone instead of UTC
sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
```

BTW. Hard-coding date format is not the best of ideas. Unless you have a good reason not to, you should use the one that is valid for end user's Locale (`DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, locale);`). Otherwise you create i18n defect (who cares, I know).

Comment: I didn't think that way but I like the way you do. Is it faster than using Calendar ? You said that sometimes you can't use Calendar, why ?

Comment: I don't know if it is faster than Calendar (I can't issue such a strong statement without using profiler). Also, I didn't say that I can't use Calendar, all I meant there are some platforms that simply do not contain Calendar implementation (for example Google App Engine). In that case developers have to stick to Date. That is unless GAE allows you to upload ICU for example

Answer (score 0):

If you're confused what to use between `Calendar.HOUR` & `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`. go with `Calendar.MILLISECOND`

```
val nextHour: Date = Calendar.getInstance().also {
        it.time = Date() // set your date time here
    }.also {
        it.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // 1 Hour
    }.time
```