# Add 1 hour to current time in android

Tags: java, android, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to increment time by 1 hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950417/how-to-increment-time-by-1-hour)

I am using this code to get the current date and time

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
System.out.println("current time date" + currentDateandTime);
```

Now I want to add 1 hour to this. I searched but I'm not getting the answer I want. Now I'm getting like this:

```
current time date2012:12:13:12:05
```

I want an answer like `2012:12:13:13:05` in 24hr format.

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12366336/1289716) that will help you sure...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

try as:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

Date date = sdf.parse(currentDateandTime);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);

System.out.println("Time here "+calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 20):

You can increment date like this before passing it to sdf.format(date)

```
   Date a=new Date();
   a.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()+(60*60*1000));
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.add(Calendar.HOUR,1);
System.out.println(now.getTime());
```